# Can new colours be given to new tags?

Tags: macos, finder-tag

I wanted to add new tags to the standard set AND to give them colours of their own but I have not been able to do it. For instance, I would like to have a brand-new Black tag. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Nacho

P.S. Notice that I am referring to Yosemite

Comment: As of Mavericks and moving into Yosemite, Apple has not yet invested in allowing this feature. The only thing you can do right now is create a service that adds selected items to a specific folder if you wanted to go that route

Comment: Thanks @soulshined. Would you, please, expand on that solution a bit further? Besides, is there any programmatic workaround to my question? I read some time ago that Yosemite had moved to JavaScript for OS/Finder task programming. If so, are there any resources that you know and that could help me along that way (any reference on the details of Mac OSX through JS, for instance)? Is it worth the effort, anyway? Thanks again!

Comment: I haven't heard about that. It maybe true, but I'm a firm believer in not pretending like I know things for the sake of looking smart. So I will leave that at that. Even if it was true, in order to change hard coded properties in the OS you have to run sudo commands. And there is a different in running a Java Script and executing a command by JavaScript code. I would be very conservative with sudo in this case, for a cosmetic fix. I'm at work so it's hard for me to expand on my comment in the amount of characters allowed or to post a tutorial so I will just add links to another comment

Comment: [Folder Actions](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_use_folder_actions_automator) can create automated actions (I.e., move files with a specific tag or finder comment or metadata to a new folder) [Services](http://www.macosxautomation.com/services/learn/tut01/index.html) are added to right click menu that you can perform actions with. Automator is a highly underutilized tool. You should take advantage of it in this case since altering something so simple will require complex coding. If either of the options are useful to you let me know I will create one when I get home to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the set tag colours; red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, or gray.

You're not able to set your own colour, so the closest colour for you would probably be gray.